# Is it possible to Send id of the tag whose data is to fetched along with Jsoup.connect(url) method?

Tags: jsoup

I want to fetch data from a particular website. Instead of getting the whole DOM and then iterating over it to fetch the data, Is it possible to send the id of the tag and get that particular data? Please help

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in method in Jsoup to fetch only elements matching a selector from a URL.  Just the usual:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
Elements section = doc.select("#id-you-are-interested-in");
```

is the way to go.  Don't worry; even if Jsoup did include a method like `Elements section = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com", "#id-you-are-interested-in");`, the entire document would still need to be fetched and parsed before Jsoup returned the `#id-you-are-interested-in` section.  Perhaps this isn't what you were getting at, but I'm just saying that there wouldn't be a measurable performance benefit to Jsoup including a method like this.  It would just be for convenience.